# Adding auto slide to my jquery auto slider

Tags: jquery, slider, autoscroll

I have tried everything to add an auto slider function to this jquery slider. I am pretty new to jquery so apologies for any shoddy knowledge. The current coding is as follows in the slider.js file:

});

```
    $slidewrap.filter('[data-autorotate]').each(function() {
        var auto,
            $el         = $(this),
            speed       = $el.attr('data-autorotate'),
            slidenum    = $el.find(opt.slide).length,
            autoAdvance = function() {
                var $slider  = $el.find(opt.slider),
                    active   = -( $(opt.slider).getPercentage() / 100 ) + 1;

                switch( active ) {
                    case slidenum: 
                        clearInterval(auto);

                        auto = setInterval(function() {
                            autoAdvance();
                            $slider.trigger("nextprev", { dir: 'prev' });   
                        }, speed);

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        clearInterval(auto);

                        auto = setInterval(function() {
                            autoAdvance();                              
                            $slider.trigger("nextprev", { dir: 'next' });   
                        }, speed);

                        break;
                }
            };
```

Would be grateful for any tips or hints!

Comment: create a jsfiddle example

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didnt really seem to help. The issue I am having mainly is where or what to actually change.